# Does setting the image of a PictureBox to the same image force a redraw?

Tags: c#, image, winforms, paint, repaint

I have a background thread that checks the communication status of a hardware device (a camera) and updates an image on my form accordingly with a green circle or red X.

```
public bool cameraStatus;

public MainForm()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   // add the UpdateDisplay function to a dictionary that will be periodically called
   updateMethods.Add(new EventHandler(UpdateDisplay));
}

public void UpdateDisplay()
{
   if (cameraStatus)
      imgCameraStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.camera_good;
   else
      imgCameraStatus.Image = Properties.Resources.camera_bad;
}
```

The `UpdateDisplay` function gets called quite often, ever 50 ms or so. The majority of the time `cameraStatus` does not change so `imgCameraStatus.Image` keeps being set to the same value.

The image does not flicker and I am wondering if the image actually gets redrawn by the window each time or not, since the source does not change. I am not sure how to get to the lower-level painting function calls in the WinForms paint cycle.

Comment: May I ask why you're asking about this? I mean, do you have a problem you're trying to solve, like excess painting, or lack of painting?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Although I'm dealing with just one camera right now this is a scalable project and I could have 5 or more later on. I want to avoid unnecessary redraws so as to not have any performance issues (a lot of other UI stuff gets updated in `UpdateDisplay` calls in my code so I want these methods as streamlined as possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,f67adf711ae5bec3,references), setting the `Image` property calls a private method called `InstallNewImage`. This method will always call `Invalidate` which will schedule a redraw of the `PictureBox` in the message queue.